# How to access a website hosted on an Ubuntu virtual machine on Azure?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, nginx, asp.net

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.10 virtual machine located on Azure and I'm accessing it via a PuTTY client. I've installed required software like Nginx and Mono, and I'm trying to host ASP.NET 5 webapp on Ubuntu.

Which IP address can be used instead of domain name (because I don't have one :) ) to test webapp hosted on Ubuntu? I want to access website from anywhere, Windows, my phone, etc.

In one tutorial, these are the Nginx configurations in .conf file

```
server {
                listen 80;
                server_name <domain-name> www.<domain.name>;
            
                client_max_body_size 10M;
            
                location / {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:5004/;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                    proxy_buffering off;
                }
            }
```

I can't see the website inside Ubuntu because I don't have any kind of GUI installed.

Answer (score 1):

There is default file in the dir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ which hosts the default page when you hit server's IP in the browser.

If you have single web app which you wish to access with server's IP then remove the default host file by running below command

- **unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**
  (the filename may be 00-default or default)

If you have multiple web apps then add default_Server tag in the web app host file which you wish to open with server's IP, as below;

```
server {
                listen 80 **default_server**;
                server_name <domain-name> www.<domain.name>;
            
                client_max_body_size 10M;
            
                location / {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:5004/;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                    proxy_buffering off;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your *listen* line with this one:

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

nginx will answer to all requests that come on the IP address directly, so all you have to do is use the same address for http as the one you use for putty.